# Add event listener to button inside template literal

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, template-literals

I'm inserting this template literal into a table with a forEach loop. How do I attach an event listener to the button on every iteration?

This just attaches the event listener to the first button in the table:

```
function renderMenu(doc) {
  const table = `
    <tr data-id=${doc.id}>
        <td>${doc.data().number}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().name}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().ingredients}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().price}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().category}</td>
        <td><button class="btn-remove">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>`

  menu.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', table)

  let removeBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-remove')

  //Delete items
  removeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      ...
  })
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: @Jeto should mention that they will still need to loop over the individual nodes that returns, because addEventListener can not be called on a NodeList.

Comment: @Jeto Yes but then I have to iterate over every node. And if I do that outside this function the elements are not created yet

Comment: Actually you're right, I've deleted that comment. I'll post an answer below instead.

Comment: _“Yes but then I have to iterate over every node”_ - a) so what?, and b) if you don’t like that, then use event delegation instead.

Comment: @misorude Ok I thought that would be inefficient to loop through the nodes on every iteration. Since this function is called inside a forEach loop.

Comment: Okay, then this should not assign the handlers in a loop over all elements, because that way you would be adding additional handlers to all previously existing elements each time. So select only the _last_ such button element, and only add the handler for that one specifically …? Or do it after the loop, if that is possible within your current logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is add a `data-` attribute to your button:

```
`... <button data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"> ...`
```

and target it with:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"]`);
```

**Demo** (I took some liberty to rename a few things):

```js
const table = document.querySelector('[data-my-table]');

function addDoc(doc) {
  const row = `
    <tr data-id=${doc.id}>
      <td>${doc.number}</td>
      <td>${doc.name}</td>
      <td>${doc.ingredients}</td>
      <td>${doc.price}</td>
      <td>${doc.category}</td>
      <td><button data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}" class="btn-remove">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>`;

  table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);

  const removeBtn = document.querySelector(`[data-remove-button-id="${doc.id}"]`);

  removeBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(`deleted row ${e.target.dataset.removeButtonId}`);
  });
}

addDoc({id: 1, number: 1, name: 'foo', ingredients: 'salt', price: 8.5, category: 'food'});
addDoc({id: 2, number: 2, name: 'foo', ingredients: 'salt', price: 8.5, category: 'food'});
addDoc({id: 3, number: 3, name: 'foo', ingredients: 'salt', price: 8.5, category: 'food'});
```

```html
<table data-my-table></table>
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!