# How to create dynamic modals in Javascript. No frameworks

Tags: javascript, html

I have a products page on my ecommerce website displaying images and information for six products, three of which were hardcoded in html and three that were created dynamically with Javascript. I want the user to be able to click on any product and see a pop-up modal with information unique to that product. Is there a way to achieve this without having to write code out for each modal?  At the moment I've coded one modal and when you click on any of the first three products you will get the same modal popping up. Again, I want to be able to do this dynamically but I'm not sure how to approach this. Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/Montpellier81/pen/qBpYLxm

My code:

HTML:

```
<h2>Hardcoded HTML - How to add dynamic modals?</h2>
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="product-card">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img id="image" src="https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod1.jpg" alt="image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h3 class="product-brand">Kettle 1</h3>
      <span class="price">$12.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-card">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img id="image" src="https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod2.jpg" alt="image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h3 class="product-brand">Kettle 2</h3>
      <span class="price">$34.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-card">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img id="image" src="https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod3.jpg" alt="image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h3 class="product-brand">Kettle 3</h3>
      <span class="price">$49.99</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <i class="modal-close fa-solid fa-xmark">X</i>
    <div class="modal-leftside">
      <img id="modal-image" src="https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod1.jpg" alt="image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-rightside">
      <div class="modal-detail">
        <h2 class="modal-brand">Kettle 1</h2>
        <h3 class="modal-price">$12.99</h3>
        <p class="modal-description">Here's more information about the Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque debitis voluptatum doloremque. Debitis quidem, praesentium enim est quod sunt architecto voluptates dolorum minus nobis. Quae incidunt ut ipsum consequatur veritatis. <br> product</p>
        <span class="modal-buyBtn">Add to Cart</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Dynamically added HTML - How to add event listeners?</h2>
<div class="container-2">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-1,
.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.product-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border: 1px purple solid;
  margin: 0; 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.product-info {
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
}
.product-image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.product-image img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-leftside {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
#modal-image {
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.modal-buyBtn {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
.modal-close {
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const modalContent = document.querySelector(".modal-content");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".modal-close");
const productCard = document.querySelectorAll(".product-card");

const products = [
  {
    img: "https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod4.jpg",
    price: "$17.32",
    name: "Kettle 4",
    description: "Description 4"
  },
  {
    img: "https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod5.jpg",
    price: "$46.01",
    name: "Kettle 5",
    description: "Description 5"
  },
  {
    img: "https://montpellier81.github.io/kettles/prod6.jpg",
    price: "$52.11",
    name: "Kettle 6",
    description: "Description 6"
  }
];

// Newly created HTML elements - how to add event listeners to each image?

let html = "";
products.map((product) => {
  html += `
            <div class="product-card">
                <div class="product-image">
                    <img id="image" src="${product.img}" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3 class="product-brand">${product.name}</h3>  
                    <span class="new-price">${product.price}</span>
  
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
  product - image;
});
document.querySelector(".container-2").innerHTML = html;

// Event Listeners on product image to display modal
productCard.forEach((product, index) => {
  product.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    closeModal.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    };
  });
});
```

update: Event delegation to add listeners to all product cards

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.matches("div")){
    console.log("Click added")
  }   
})

const newProduct = document.createElement("div")
newProduct.style.width = "210px"
newProduct.style.height = "100px"
newProduct.style.backgroundColor = "green"
document.body.append(newProduct)
```

My inkling is that the solution would involve the use of data attributes, creating an array for each value (e.g. price, name, description) and linking individual modals to the array via data attribute, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Can someone nudge me towards a solution that does not involve using Bootstrap or JQuery?

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/Montpellier81/pen/qBpYLxm

The second part of my question involves the products that were added dynamically. How do I add event listeners to them like I did with the first set of products? Specifically how do I access and manipulate html elements that were dynamically created?

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow so please I hope I've given enough information. I would really appreciate any help as I've spent about 4 days trying to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation. Add event on products parent, when user click on specific product, get that product information by event e.target.closest(".my-product") and open modal with that product information.
Add .my_product class to all product element.

Event Delegation is basically a pattern to handle events efficiently. Instead of adding an event listener to each and every similar element, we can add an event listener to a parent element and call an event on a particular target using the . target property of the event object.

Comment: Hi Pardip, I created a new div using ```createElement``` and was able to attach an event listener to it through event delegation, But I still can't get it to work for my original items that weren't created with the createElement method. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Montpellier81/pen/qBpYLxm updated

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ts9cSjJNudQ60UKWs1fQJUKx7xPqxY8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Pardip, solution works great with the hardcoded elements, however nothing happens when I click on the dynamically generated items in the second row. Is there another way to target these elements? I found a question similar to mine here:   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556671/add-event-listener-to-button-inside-template-literal)
and tried adding a data attribute to my product card like the solution suggested again nothing happened. 
<div class="product-card" data-card-id=${products._id}>